# MySQL SUM and return multiple other rows results

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have following MySQL Tables:

TABLE: reg_users

```
-----------------
  id | username 
-----------------
  1     a
  2     b
  3     c
```

TABLE: bill

```
-----------------------
  id | m12     | p12 |
-----------------------
  1     13.69     1
  2     0.00      1
  3    269.89     1
```

```
SELECT b.p12 AS payed, 
       d.id, 
       b.m12 AS prev_month, 
       b.m12 AS curr_month, 
       username, 
       SUM(b.m12) AS total_prev_month 
FROM `reg_users` d 
LEFT JOIN `bill` b ON d.id = b.id 
ORDER BY d.`id` DESC;
```

I only get one row result and need to get all results (3 rows result with total_prev_month SUMMED together for each row so this row need to have values for each row 283.58.

Using GROUP BY i get correct total_prev_month value but i get only one row results...and i need in this example 3 rows results like:

```
------------------------------------------------
  payed | id     | username |  total_prev_month
------------------------------------------------
  1        1         a              283.58
  1        2         b              283.58
  1        3         c              283.58
```

Comment: `SUM(b.m12) OVER () AS total_prev_month`

Comment: window analytic functions such as `SUM(b.m12) OVER () AS total_prev_month` might be used for DB version 8.0, what's your DB version?

Comment: DB version is 7.3...above answer works great..thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a subquery within the SELECT-list :

```
SELECT b.p12 AS payed, d.id, username, 
       (SELECT ROUND(SUM(m12),2) FROM `bill` ) AS total_prev_month 
  FROM `reg_users` d 
  JOIN `bill` b ON d.id = b.id 
 ORDER BY d.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6f60463f5fe4bc343daee3ad0675c920)</kbd>